# angular - display dates that are equal or greater than today

Tags: angular, momentjs

I've got an array containing dates. What I want to do is to only display those that are equal or greater than today on my html page. I used moment.isAfter() but at the moment all the dates are displayed. What do I do wrong ?

**html**

```
<div *ngIf="isShown" id="divshow">
  <div *ngFor="let rez of dates" style="cursor: pointer;">

        {{rez.date}} par {{rez.text}}

  </div>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
  dates = [
    { date: "2020-11-01", text: "réservé par équipe 1" },
    { date: "2020-11-20", text: "réservé par un équipe 2" }
  ];

  todayDate:Date = new Date();

  toggleShow() {
    this.isShown = ! this.isShown;

    let now = this.datepipe.transform(this.todayDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    for (var dat of this.dates) {
    let range = dat.date;
    let futureDate = moment(range).isAfter(now);
    console.log(futureDate);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.dates = this.dates.filter(d => {return moment(d.date).isAfter(now)});` should work. Be aware that if you execute the code you will lose all the date that are before today.

Comment: It was a pleasure, you can also use a `pipe` to display just those dates that are after today. This way you are not changing any data in your array.

Answer (score -1):

```
this.dates = this.dates.filter(item => {return moment(item.date).isAfter(now)});
```